# ESP32-C3 schematic question

Tags: esp32

I'm building a board with the new ESP32 chips and have some questions,

- Firstly on the data sheet it shows resistors between the USB and the ESP with two resistors at R0, I assume this is so you can cross the traces on the same side of the board?
- Secondly, it shows capacitors on the D+ and D- lines, but doesn't mention anywhere in the sheet what these values should be? Would this be decided based on the type of USB connector?
- Thirdly, on the EN Pin there is a capacitor, on the datasheet it suggests C = 1 μF however on all the other ESP datasheets this 0.1F not sure what to follow.
- Finally, from IO0 and IO1 it looks like an external crystal? But it's not connected, in the devkit this connection is left disconnected so not sure if it's required

[image: ESP32-C3 datasheet]

Answer (score 1):

All things marked with NC are not required, for example you don't need an external crystal, but you can add one if you need higher timing precision.

For the TBD capacitor connected to USB, I've never seen that before, but you probably won't need them. 0ohm resistor are there so that you can disconnect the chip from USB port and have more IO pins, you won't need them if it's fine to connect to USB port at all times.

The capacitor on EN pin need to be designed together with R1, just make sure the timing constant of this RC circuit is reasonable. Usually 0.22uF with 10kOhm works.

Comment: That makes sense, id assume the D+ and D- will need to be a parralel pair from usb to the ESP? Also how would i calculate the timing? im getting 0.22uf, 0.1uf , 1uf from different sources, all with 10k pull up

Comment: As long as you keep the traces short, you don't need parallel pairs, as the baud rate is usually <1MBps. For the capacitor and resistor, just pick a random number you like in this range and it will work.

Comment: @Wjx: USB is *never* <1MBps.  Low speed is 1.5M, Full speed is 12M, High speed is 480M.  If your application data is <1Mbps you will have lots of idle time, but the USB frequency will not decrease.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer about your 2nd question about caps on the USB lines.

it is so you can bypass higher frequency noise generated by the USB controller,
you do not need large capacitors, I use in my USB 3 design 47pF 0402 C0G capacitors.